# How to move postgres into docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I usually attach to postgres by typing in the terminal:

```
psql -U user db
```

I want to move postgres into docker container:

```
docker run -v /var/lib/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

Then I run command and have an error:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user 
psql: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist
```

I expected that `-v /var/lib/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql` will make possible to reach `db` by `user`. But it doesn't happen. How to make it correctly?

Comment: Can you please add the version of PostgreSQL you are using locally and in the image? You are not specifying a Docker image tag so it is using `latest`. At the moment, `latest` is the same as `9.6`. If your local PostgreSQL has a cluster name other than `main` and a different version that the Docker container you are running then the default data directory will not be correct and it will likely be running on an empty bootstrapped PostgreSQL. You can check your `/var/lib/postgresql` local directory to see if it created any new folders.

Comment: @AndyShinn, yes, my local folder contains `9.5` folder. I tried to `docker run postgres:9.5 --args`, but it's the same effect. I suspect postgres configs in container are stored in another places, so `-v /var/lib` doesn't give any effect.

Comment: According to the docs at https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ there is a `PGDATA` environment variable you can set. You may just need to set this to the actual data directory for your PostgreSQL install. But this is hard to solve given the information. You should list out the configuration files and directory structures you have locally as the information will be helpful to solve it.

Comment: you need to run psql  as postgres: su postgres sh -c "psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user "